# How would I achieve this layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need it to be responsive.. I've tried setting larger image as a div background but it's not responsive.. I end up with the two right images large than the large image... I'm not sure what to do.. I'm using bootstrap, please see my code and any advice would be appreciated.

Also, the two images on the right will display:none on mobile.. so it's not mobile I'm worried about, its from ipad and up that I need it to be responsive and all stay aligned

[image]

```css
.large-image {
    div {
        position: relative;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.large-image-two {
    div {
        height: 50vw;
        @include breakpoint(up, xl) {
            height: 43vw;
        }
    }
    @include breakpoint(up, xl) {
        max-height: 1100px;
    }
}

.tile {
    display: none;
    @include breakpoint(up, lg) {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="image-tile">
    <div class="container-fluid padding-sides padding-large pt-0">
        <div class="row">
 
            <div class="col-xxl-10 col-lg-9 col-12 large-image large-image-two">
                <div class="full-height" style="background-image: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/847/1370/700.jpg?hmac=kz_PXEVjCOQtig90AKAetNcWNNoJdWMjRMYhOLc6r7w)"></div> 
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-xxl-2 col-lg-3 col-12 tile">
                <div class="row d-flex flex-column full-height">
                    
                        <div class="top-image col-8">
                            <img class="full-width" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/682/250/400.jpg?hmac=ub0-x7bHa0z6PHozDd9A5baHp22hyWuq0NZuhHYmmBE">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-4">
                            <img class="full-width" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/545/250/270.jpg?hmac=lfBUvuMl6_uUp1lJI6e4A7KBiB4vzkocSlai_L0fUyE">
                        </div>
                 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please post your rendered HTML (without the PHP code). We need to know what image sizes you are working with, so also add in placeholder images (using something like https://via.placeholder.com/100x100 ) for each of your images.

Comment: I have just updated post with placeholder images

Comment: @birdyoung so you want the same layout in larger device and tablets, and on mobile you want to hide the right column. is this you want

Comment: yeah that's right